# MYSql search perfomance problems

Tags: mysql, performance

```
account
act_id | act_name | grp_id  | grp_id_2
2      | test     |      4  | 10

promotion
pml_id | act_id   | grp_id 
2      | 2        | null
3      | null     | 4
4      | null     | 10
```

I have two tables, shown above (trimmed down). Account has about 15000 records, promotion about 20000.

Customer basically wants it so that they could search for an account name, say 'test'. And it would show the promotions 2, 3 and 4.

Promotion 3 would show because the account 'test' has grp_id = 4.

Promotion 4 would show because account 'test' has grp_id_2 = 10.

I originally did this with a couple of joins

```
SELECT pml_id FROM promotion 
    LEFT JOIN account AS account1 ON promotion.act_id = account1.act_id
    LEFT JOIN account AS account2 ON promotion.grp_id = account2.grp_id
    LEFT JOIN account AS account3 ON promotion.grp_id = account3.grp_id_2
WHERE account1.act_name LIKE 'test%' or account2.act_name LIKE 'test%' 
      or account3.act_name LIKE  'test%'
GROUP BY pml_id
```

The problem with this is this ended up taking a long time when I started having to join 5 times to the account table. It also gave me about 10000000 records (without the group by). Most of the promotions use a grp_id, rarely do they use an act_id.

Is there any way to search the act_name column quickly in this scenario? Without having to do so many joins?

I have single indexes on act_id, pml_id, grp_id, grp_id_2

Note: This is part of a query where the user may not search by account. I.E the where clause may not always be there

Comment: Is it possible for multiple rows in the account table to have the same act_name?

Comment: Yes, they don't have any at the moment but they could in the future, thanks, you just made me realise something else, those should be likes instead of direct = to. I'll make the edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `INNER JOIN` instead to avoid scanning the entire table :

```
SELECT p.pml_id 
FROM account a
INNER JOIN promotion p
  ON (p.act_id = a.act_id OR p.grp_id = a.grp_id OR p.grp_id = a.grp_id_2)
WHERE a.act_name LIKE "test%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this any faster?

```
SELECT pml_id FROM promotion p
  LEFT JOIN account a
  ON (p.act_id = a.act_id OR p.grp_id = a.grp_id OR p.grp_id = a.grp_id_2)
WHERE a.act_name LIKE "test%";
```

Try this one as well, if you have an index on act_id, this should be quite a bit faster:

```
SELECT * FROM promotion p
LEFT JOIN account a
  ON (p.act_id = a.act_id OR p.grp_id = a.grp_id OR p.grp_id = a.grp_id_2)
WHERE a.act_id IN (
    SELECT act_id FROM account WHERE act_name LIKE "test%"
)
```

Comment: I tried the first one and putting them all on one line took 70 secs before I had to kill it. For the 2nd query, I should have mentioned this earlier, see edit to question, the where clause may not always be included (as the user may not search by account name)